# CSS Left Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I am having the code

```
<div class="slidermoveImgCont center float-left">
    <img id="SImg1"  src="img/nat1.jpg" alt="gg" class="first simg alwaysfirst" name="actualImage1">
    <img id="SImg2"  src="img/nat2.jpg" alt="gg" class="simg" name="actualImage2">
    <img id="SImg3"  src="img/nat3.jpg" alt="gg" class="simg" name="actualImage3">
    <img id="SImg4"  src="img/nat4.jpg" alt="gg" class="simg" name="actualImage4">
    <img id="SImg5"  src="img/nat5.jpg" alt="gg" class="simg" name="actualImage5">
    <img id="SImg6"  src="img/nat6.jpg" alt="gg" class="last simg" name="actualImage6">
    <img id="SImg7"  src="img/nat7.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg" name="actualImage7">
    <img id="SImg8"  src="img/nat8.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg" name="actualImage8">
    <img id="SImg9"  src="img/nat9.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg" name="actualImage9">
    <img id="SImg10" src="img/nat10.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg" name="actualImage10">
    <img id="SImg11" src="img/nat11.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg" name="actualImage11">
    <img id="SImg12" src="img/nat12.jpg" alt="gg" class="dns simg alwayslost" name="actualImage12">
</div>
```

Where always i show six images at a time, i plan to show the remaining images on increasing or decreasing the left value like sliding.how do i acheive it.I give width to the containing div and overflow:hidden to the containing div and then i increase/decrease the left of the containing div of the images, i am not able to see the remaining images. I plan to try out my image slider on my own.Please help me in this.

more info:i added the image which i want to acheive , in that image, only 6 images are shown, on clicking the arrow button, i want to scroll using the left property with animation

Comment: Could you show us an example of what you're exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: i added the image and what i am trying to acheive.

Comment: Why not use a jquery slider plugin - there are a lot out there and as you don't seem to know how to write your own it would be easier to get a ready made one

Comment: i just am trying how to implement it. i think of this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/L4HRY/

Basically you nest a div inside your container (with fixed with) where all images are next to each other. You set overflow: hidden on your container so only the images that fit inside the container are visible:

```
<div class="slidermoveImgCont center float-left">
    <div>
        //snap images
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slidermoveImgCont
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slidermoveImgCont div
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Then you move your inner div around with `left` and `right`

That's *the concept*

Comment: Thanks reinder.This is what exactly i want.You save my day.